# Recorrer elemento de lista de elementos por find_elements_by_class_name en Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

estoy empezando con Selenium tengo el siguiente código html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="error">
      <h4>Error 1</h4>
      <p>Mi error 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
      <h4>Error 2</h4>
      <p>Este es el Error 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
      <h4>Error 3</h4>
      <p>Acceder</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ok">
      <h4>Esto OK</h4>
      <p>Esto esta OK</p>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
      <h4>Error 4</h4>
      <p>Otro error</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bien, lo que quiero recuperar el el valor de la etiqueta "**p**" con el valor de texto **"Acceder"**

para ello en el Selenium Webdriver en Python tengo el siguiente código

```
elementos=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("error") 
for elem in elementos   
    ### aqui quiero selecionar la etiqueta "<p>" de elem
```

pero no tengo claro como puedo seleccionarlo para recoger el texto.

Salu2

Answer (score 0):

Yo intentaria utilizar busquedas por xPath o por CSS. Te dejo un ejemplo de xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//p[text()='Acceder']")
```

Con esto no te hace falta ningun bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Usando cualquiera de los métodos que selenium te da para localizar un elemento (por nombre, por clase, por id, por selector css, por xpath, ...) el resultado que obtienes es un [`webelement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html?highlight=webelement#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement). Este objeto tiene a su vez los mismos métodos que el `driver`, por lo que puedes volver a buscar en su interior por nombre, clase, id, etc...

Por ejemplo, el siguiente bucle te sacaría los textos de las etiquetas `<p>` que estén dentro de un otro elemento con clase `"error"`, que más o menos es lo que intentabas hacer en el código que has puesto en la pregunta:

```
elementos=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("error") 
for elem in elemento:
    p = elem.find_element_by_tag_name("p")
    print(p[0].text)
```

Pero puedes ahorrarte repetir búsquedas si los elementos que seleccionas son directamente los `<p>`, en lugar de los `<div>`. Para esto necesitas expresar que quieres "los elementos p que sean hijos de un elemento div de la clase "error". Esto puedes expresarlo mediante Xpath, o mediante expresiones CSS, según a qué estés más acostumbrado. Por ejemplo:

```
# Usando selector css
elementos = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.error p")

# Usando xpath
elementos = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='error']/p")
```

De cualquiera de las dos formas obtienes la lista con los `<p>` que te interesaban y puedes iterar por ella:

```
for p in elementos:
    print(p.text)
```

Ahora bien, si no necesitas todos los `p`, sino sólo aquellos que contengan el texto ' Acceder'  una expresión Xpath más elaborada que retornaría únicamente esos sería:

```
elementos = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='error']/p[text()='Acceder']")
```

Comment: muchas gracias por las respuestas. El tema es que esos "div" aparecen al rellenar un formulario por si aparece un error. Sabiendo ya como recuperar el texto de la etiqueta "p" ya puedo buscar si existe el "div" y si es el caso, recuperar el texto para verificar si se ha guardado correctamente Saludos

Comment: @Thenine ¿Pregunta resuelta entonces? En ese caso puedes marcar como aceptada (✓) mi respuesta.